# Nullpointer exception in Springboot application used as dependent jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

i am using a springboot application as a dependency in my standalone java application.

I am getting null pointer exception for autowired (bService) class used in utility method.

Main method in parentapplication ---

```
{
BatchProcessor obj = new BatchProcessor;
obj.getBatchStatus(123);

}
```

------------------- Spring Boot Ccode ----

```
public class BatchProcessor {
@Autowire
IBatchService bSerice;
public int getBatchStatus(int batch_id){ return bSerice.getStauts(batch_id);}
}

interface IBatchService {}
@Service
public class CBABatchService implements IbatchService{ public int getStatus(int id){}}
```

Comment: The annotation `@service` should have the first letter capitalized, `@Service` :) Moreover, to let Spring resolve the dependency from `IBatchService`, you need that the `CBABatchService` is in a package that Spring can scan

Comment: Sorry riccardo.cardin - service is @Service only. my main method is in different application and BtachProcessor is in different sprint boot application which i am using as jar.

Comment: Yep, understand. Does your application use Spring to resolve dependencies? Anyway, if you instantiate the class `BatchProcessor` using the `new` operator directly, there is no way to Spring to kick in :)